# Can I start a bundle at a specific time without starting it manually

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I have a bundle up and running in servicemix. I wanted to know if there is a way I could make some configuration changes and have it started automatically at say 7:30 in the morning.
I am new to servicemix. 
thanks for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use Camel route in your bundles, you can also use the [Quartz2](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html) component to schedule some processing.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible to schedule bundles being started|stopped out of the box. But ServiceMix / Karaf is scriptable, so you can have some perl script (or any other) and have it trigger at 7:30 in the morning to execute a script that starts the bundle.

For example check out the karaf client example here: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/esb_runtime/ESBRuntimeConnect.html

You can google a bit more about karaf client script.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful. I went with the cron job setup to achieve this.